# Why are my Gladiolus aiming at the sun?

Tags: flowers, bulbs

My Gladioli are coming up, but they are bent at about a 90 degree. They're in full sun with grass compost dirt. I planted them just a little bit under the surface.

Why are they doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem with gladioli, usually because they're not planted deep enough, or are not in full sun. I'm not sure what 'just a little bit under the surface' means, but they're best planted 4-6 inches deep, 4 inches apart. If you plant them 6 inches deep, you're much less likely to get this problem and its also less likely they'll need staking.